# node permission based on a cck user reference field

Tags: 6, entities, users

I have a cck user reference field in a content type in drupal 6. I want only the user selected by that field can view the node content.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [User Reference Access](https://drupal.org/project/userref_access) module - it directly addresses this requirement:

> This module works with CCK userreference fields and the node_access
>   module to add additional grants to nodes.
>
> To enable userref_access on a node, edit the userreference field for
>   the node type and check the "Use User Reference Access" box.
>
> Any users that are referenced by this field will be given view
>   permissions for the node, all other useres will be denied access to
>   the node.